# How to find a List of Live videos using Youtube api?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to get a list of live events from any channels using Youtube Api v3

I added the official NuGet packages to my wpf project:

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;

and I added OAuth authentication in a button click:

```
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("mydowloadedjsonfile.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly }, "user",
            CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("YouTubeAPI")
            ).Result;
    }

    var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "YouTubeAPI"
    });
```

This code works great, it opens a Browser to get authenticated and allow the youtube permissions to my user

After that I am trying to get a list of live events but I am failling:

```
        var request = service.Search.List("snippet");
        request.Q = "live event";//I know this is wrong...
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        var response = request.Execute();
```

Obliviously I am doing it wrong, can someone point to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by using this request instead:

```
        var request = service.Search.List("snippet");
        request.Q = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
        request.EventType = SearchResource.ListRequest.EventTypeEnum.Live;
        request.Type = "video";
        request.MaxResults = 10;
```

request.Type is needed otherwise you will get google exception. Api developers made it bery ugly... it is begging to be an enum or something